# Subtract 2 fields of a data table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have the following problem.

I have a table lets call it Activity.

In this table there are 3 fields one is the **date_start**, the second is **date_end** and the third is the **activity_type**, which correspond the date that the activity start and ends and the type of activity for example physical activity and eating.

I would like to find the median time period that a activity_type lasts.

For example:

```
Activity.where(activity_type: "Eating healthy")
```

So I want to apply in this question, a sum statement with the time difference between the **date_start** and **date_end**.

How I can find the time differences of all the same type activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL's [`DATEDIFF`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp) function to find the number of days between each date value. You can then use `ActiveRecord`'s [`average`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average) method to find out the median/average number of days.

```
condition = {activity_type: "Eating healthy"}
sql_string = "DATEDIFF(day, date_end, date_start)"
Activity.where(condition).average(sql_string) #=> numeric value
```

You can get the data for all activity types by grouping the rows, like so:

```
Activity.group(:activity_type).average(sql_string) #=> Hash with numeric values
```

But this also depends on which database you're using. For example, the `DATEDIFF` function doesn't exist for SQLite. You will have to lookup the appropriate date-difference function that you can use for your database.

Comment: Thank you Humza for your answer, the issue is that I do use SQLite and I do not know how to structure a DATEDIFF with this. I saw strftime but I have some confusion.

Comment: SQLite's `julianday` function will return the number of days since a particular date (you can look it up). You can subtract the `julianday` values of each date, and then find the average of the result. e.g. `Activity.group(:activity_type).average("julianday(date_end) - julianday(date_start)").to_f`